# Current Source - MOSFET vs Bipolar NPN/PNP for stability

Tags: transistors, mosfet, current-source

Consider the schematic below.

There are several pro an con for each, I would like to focus here solely on regulation stability. (Not voltage drop or opamp current as this is already answered).

I currently use the MOSFET version on a project and works pretty fine, after tuning several filters to improve stability it can reach about 0.1% stability.

However, I was wondering, given Bipolar have a "flatter" response, if using a bipolar would have a more stable output as it would swing less as it doesn't have gate capacitance and has a wider control region.

[image]

Comment: What, approximately, are the load and sense resistor values, and the current? '0.1% stability' means what to you? Overshoot? Line regulation? Load regulation?

Comment: Current is 1A max, supply is 12V and it regulates a string of LED, so we regulate the LED output. Sense resistor is 2ohm. Actually the load is above the mosfet.

Comment: Please include the actual circuit you are asking about in your question, not some different circuit. Also explain what "several filters" you're talking about.

Comment: schematic updated

Comment: Stability of the circuit you posted probably depends on the thermal variation if the zener. But I have no idea if this applies to your actual circuit.

Comment: I still don't see "several filters" in your schematic.

Comment: I'm talking about regulation stability, not the control offset. This is simplified schematic, filters are irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I can use an active 0 to 4A pulse  load (NPN) and get less than 10mV ripple on 12V but it depends on hFE, Rce and Op Amp Z out http://tinyurl.com/y88tcous

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist the circuit you link is voltage regulated, not current regulated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another topology to consider (found in many *old* application notes):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkTp9P.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You have said you don't want to discuss the voltage drop involved. So although that would definitely come to my mind in this design, I've decided to follow your lead and avoid thinking more about that question.

Aside from very tiny JFET leakage current, all of the load current flows through \$R_\text{SET}\$ and it is very easy to see that fact in the above schematic. You get most of the benefits of the exponential relationship in a BJT between collector current and base-emitter voltage changes, too, and the output should be quite linear with respect to the control voltage.

(I don't think you want the above, though. The following circuit modifies your circuit with Bode in mind. If you keep your approach, you should consider it.)

---

Let's return to your circuit. If you deal with a Bode plot, I think you will find this better:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8jyN4.png)</sup>

I copied Henry's choice for \$V_\text{SET}=1\:\text{V}\$ in order to set your maximum current of \$1\:\text{A}\$. That impacted by choice for \$R_\text{SET}\$. But you can obviously change that as you see fit.

I think you should also review thoughts found in [Linear's Current Sense Circuit Collection](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/an105fa.pdf). There are a few ideas there you might also consider. In fact, the above circuit can be found as Figure 79, there.

Answer (score 2):

You can make bipolar transistor have better high-frequency noise performance than a fet, as you can bypass/LPF the base, and rely on the better passive voltage following performance of the BJT emitter follower, at frequencies above what the opamp can control.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRMkvn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The bipolar will also require less slew rate performance from the opamp as only a few hundred mv change in Vbase is needed to regulate the current.

When current is relatively low, bipolars work nicely since the HFE is high, and the opamp can drive them directly. 
Ibase is an error term if absolute current is important. i.e. you will have an error of 1/HFE  (base current is going through the sense resistor, but is not in the load. If you use a darlington, then the base current of the final transistor is coming from the load.)

Comment: The transistor has to be a Darlington to prevent load regulation error from Op Amp dynamic Zout and current limits etc  The biggest factor is ESR and Rce and supply ESR

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist You've lost me there. Single or Darlington, Ibase of the final transistor is an error term if absolute current is important. i.e. you will have an error of 1/HFE

Comment: Step load high frequency gain is good but Zout of Op Amp is 200 Ohm min or current limited.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist thats not introducing an error is it? It's just limiting the maximum base current and therefor max Iout. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Ignoring massive heatsink http://tinyurl.com/y9h6fzbv  27A step load has edge noise.

Comment: It's the input triangle causing the noise ( ripple  simulated) and thus Rce, hfe and Zout

Comment: taken to extreme to show source of load and line regulation error is series pass ESR or Rs sensitive . nite....

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist But the point about using a bipolar is you can put C at the base, reduce high frequency noise, and handle steps (without the opamp doing anything). By comparison, if you used an LM358 and a fet, the  slew rate would slaughter it (since VGS has to slew a couple of voltage)

Comment: You can also do that with a mosfet

Comment: One further consideration is that the opamp will inject current through Q1 and thus through R2 and creates an offset

Comment: @Darnien  If they had 10 milliOhm Pch MOSFETs back the 70's they would have offered it in the LM317 upgrade to 10A but the cost would rise significantly.  Now they are better but same prioce as Darlingtons with the same Rce as RdsOn but then LDO drop suffers.  so in the end MOSFET wins for ultralow dropout and line/load regulation with care on Miller cap noise.. But then a 1MHz SMPS can be more efficient and quiet too with 10mOhm

Comment: @Damien - "One further consideration is that the opamp will inject current through Q1 and thus through R2 and creates an offset" Not in this part of the space-time continuum. The feedback loop nulls out any current error. Within its limits, of course.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I think D is referring to Ibase as I discuss in the answer. The feedback keeps I-R2 correct, *not* I-Q1-Collector